# String cannot be converted to Codigo

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate, jpa, servlets

Hola estoy intentado recoger el código que yo inserto o ya existe a través de un formulario pero al usar el método getOne al que hay que pasar un objeto de tipo Codigo no sé cómo hacer esa conversión. El método getOne lo uso para obtener el código de un profesor para poder actualizar sus datos o borrar el profesor.

```
BEANS
    @Embeddable
public class Codigo implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private Integer tipo;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(Integer tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.tipo);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Codigo other = (Codigo) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.tipo, other.tipo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

    @Entity

@Table(name = "profesores")
public class Profesor implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private Codigo codigo;

    @Column(name = "nombre", length = 20, nullable = true)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "ape1", length = 15, nullable = true)
    private String ape1;

    @Column(name = "ape2", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String ape2;

    @Column(name = "escala", columnDefinition="set('s', 't') default 's'", insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private String escala;

    @Column(name = "fecha", columnDefinition="datetime default now()", insertable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar fecha;

    public Codigo getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Codigo codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApe1() {
        return ape1;
    }

    public void setApe1(String ape1) {
        this.ape1 = ape1;
    }

    public String getApe2() {
        return ape2;
    }

    public void setApe2(String ape2) {
        this.ape2 = ape2;
    }

    public String getEscala() {
        return escala;
    }

    public void setEscala(String escala) {
        this.escala = escala;
    }

    public Calendar getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

}
```

DAO del profesor, sólo hay que mirar el método getOne

```
 public class ProfesorDAO implements IProfesorDAO {

    @Override
    public void add(Profesor profesor) {
        Session sesion = null;
        try {
            sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            sesion.save(profesor);
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(org.hibernate.JDBCException jdbce){
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Profesor> get() {
        List<Profesor> listado = null;
        Session sesion = null;
        try {
            sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            listado = sesion.createQuery(" from Profesor").list();
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(org.hibernate.JDBCException jdbce){
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.close();
            }
        }
        return listado;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Profesor profesor) {
        Session sesion = null;
        try {
            sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            sesion.delete(profesor);
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(org.hibernate.JDBCException jdbce){
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Profesor getOne(Codigo codigo) {
        Profesor profesor = new Profesor();
        Session sesion = null;
        try {
            sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            profesor = (Profesor)sesion.get(Profesor.class, codigo);
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(org.hibernate.JDBCException jdbce){
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.close();
            }
        }
        return profesor;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Profesor profesor) {
        Session sesion = null;
        try {
            sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            sesion.update(profesor);
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(org.hibernate.JDBCException jdbce){
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if(sesion != null){
                sesion.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

FORMULARIO para actualizar donde se obtiene el código

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:set var="contexto" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Actualizar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${contexto}/CSS/estilo.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="principal">
            <h2>Actualizaci&oacute;n de datos</h2>
            <form method="post" action="conclusion?op=update">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Código</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="codigo" value="${profesor.codigo}" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="nombre" value="${profesor.nombre}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Apellido 1</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="ape1" value="${profesor.ape1}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Apellido 2</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="ape2" value="${profesor.ape2}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="escala">
                                <option value="${profesor.escala}" selected>${profesor.escala}</option>
                                <option value="t">T</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fecha</td>
                        <td><input type="datetime-local" name="fecha" value="${profesor.fecha}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="boton" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

FORMULARIO para borrar donde se obtiene el código

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:set var="contexto" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Borrado</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${contexto}/CSS/estilo.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="principal">
            <h2>Elige uno para eliminar</h2>



            <form method="post" action="control?op=delete">
                <table>
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${listado}">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="registro" value="${item.codigo}" /></td>
                            <td>${item.nombre} ${item.ape1} ${item.ape2} ${item.escala} ${item.fecha}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Eliminar" class="boton" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

SERVLET donde se hacen las operaciones como actualizar (update) o borra (delete)

```
 @WebServlet(name = "Controlador", urlPatterns = {"/control"})
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        DAOFactory daof = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory();
        IProfesorDAO pdao = daof.getProfesorDAO();

        Codigo codigo = new Codigo();
        Profesor profesor = new Profesor();
        String url = null;
        switch (request.getParameter("op")) {
            case "add":
                try {
                    //BeanUtils.populate(profesor, request.getParameterMap());
                    codigo.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
                    codigo.setTipo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipo")));
                    profesor.setCodigo(codigo);
                    profesor.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombre"));
                    profesor.setApe1(request.getParameter("ape1"));
                    profesor.setApe2(request.getParameter("ape2"));
                    profesor.setEscala(request.getParameter("escala"));

                    //Se pasa a Date la fecha recibida y después se pasa a Calendar con el método setTime()
                    String s = request.getParameter("fecha");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
                    Date date = sdf.parse(s);
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(date);
                    profesor.setFecha(cal);

                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                pdao.add(profesor);
                url = "index.html";
                break;
            case "delete":
                profesor = pdao.getOne(request.getParameter("registro"));
                pdao.delete(profesor);
                url = "index.html";
                break;
            case "update":
                profesor = pdao.getOne(request.getParameter("codigo"));
                request.setAttribute("profesor", profesor);
                url = "JSP/formularioActualizar.jsp";
                break;
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }
```

El error

> String cannot be converted to Codigo

que sale en el case "delete" y "update" está en:

```
profesor = pdao.getOne(request.getParameter("registro"));

profesor = pdao.getOne(request.getParameter("codigo"));
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La firma de tu método es:

```
public Profesor getOne(Codigo codigo)
```

Es decir que tu método espera como parámetro un objeto **Codigo**.

La llamada que haces es:

```
pdao.getOne(request.getParameter("registro"));
```

y **getParameter** de request devuelve String. Tienes que construir un objeto **Codigo** en base al parametro del request o cambiar **getOne** para que reciba String.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder usar la función getOne deberías crear un Objeto y asignarle los valores que están llegando por parámetro, una vez hecho le pasarías el objeto generado al getOne.

```
Codigo codigo = new Codigo();
codigo.setRegistro(request.getParameter("registro"));
codigo.setCodigo(request.getParameter("codigo"));
profesor = pdao.getOne(request.getParameter("registro"));
```

Los tipos de datos igual no estan exactos pero es para que te hagas una idea de como debería ser.

Comment: El problema que tengo es que con Codigo, sólo puedo hacer `codigo.setId` o `codigo.setTipo` y con el `request.getParameter("registro")` o `request.getParameter("codigo")` lo que estoy obteniendo el el codigo que está en la clase Profesor como `private Codigo codigo`. Y creo que no puedo separar el id del tipo ya que es una clave primaria compuesta en la base de datos.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que por lo que dices te esta llegando un objeto codigo por parametro? En caso de ser así debes coger los valores del objeto que te llega y generar el objeto codigo. Si el problema persiste puedes compartir el repo donde lo tienes alojado y así sera más fácil dar con la solución

Comment: Gracias, he cogido esos valores que me llegan por separado y funciona! Mil gracias.

Comment: De nada. Hasta otra!